# Is the HTML .style property fully compatible with Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Consider the following Javascript command:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('phone_label')[0].style = 'color:#ec5840';
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

This article on the .style property does not indicate any issues with Safari.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Is the HTML .style property fully compatible with Safari browser? (Both desktop and iOS versions).

```js
  
  function changecolor() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('phone_label')[0].style = 'color:#ec5840';
    alert('The phone number should change to red!');  
  }
```

```html
  <p class='phone_label'>0411 111 111</p><br>
  <button onclick='changecolor()'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a functional Stack Overflow Code Snippet for us? It'd also help knowing which version of Safari you're using, after that.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025555/option-style-display-none-not-working-in-safari): This is part of a long and inconsistent tradition with Safari restricting CSS styling functionality on form elements, believing the visual language of interactive elements should be consistent with the OS

Comment: No worries @JonUleis

Comment: If you use `style.color = '#ec5840'` it works in Safari (and is consistent with the MDN reference).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959814/style-displayblock-works-in-chrome-but-not-safari suggests something to do with Safari not parsing strings in style. I'm trying to find the actual docs atm.

Comment: Thanks @RobG ! That is a really helpful solution.

Answer (score 1):

Per the MDN on [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), here are suggestions for the correct syntax:

`document.getElementsByClassName('phone_label')[0].style.cssText = 'color: #ec5840;';`

`document.getElementsByClassName('phone_label')[0].style.color = '#ec5840';`

Comment: Per the MDN docs, his current syntax is **not** wrong: "Styles can be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`)" So the question remains, why isn't it working on Safari?

Comment: @NelsonYeung Thank you for pointing that out - completely missed that sentence. Odd how they don't expand upon it, though.

Comment: @NelsonYeung Looks like that sentence was originally explicitly telling users "NOT to be assigning a string directly to the style property", until it was changed in November 2016 by someone coming from a Chrome bug report. Clearly this change wasn't ready for primetime, since not all browsers (like Safari) adhere. The diff: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style$compare?to=1140743&from=1133865

Comment: @NelsonYeung After going through the page's history, I've restored that bit to how it was less than a year ago when it was in line with W3 spec. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: That's a beautiful find! Thanks for this, I never thought about searching for the change history. This turned out more interesting than I thought.